# Remove Blur View from another subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I have added 2 subviews into my view(**EOPSessionsViewController**), **blurEffectView** and **reLogInView**.

```
    if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
        UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        blurEffectView.tag = 123;
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
    }else{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    self.reLogInView = [[ReLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReLoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:self.reLogInView.view];
    self.reLogInView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    self.reLogInView.view.center = self.view.center;
    self.reLogInView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.reLogInView.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.reLogInView.view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

I want to remove **blurEffectView** and **reLogInView** when user clicks a cancel button inside **reLogInView**. As of now, i can remove **reLogInView** with the code below.

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

---

My question is how to remove **blurEffectView** at the same time? Note that 3 of them are different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this:

```
self.reLogInView.sessionsVC = self;
```

in the first code snippet. (declare it like this):

```
@interface ReLoginViewController : (???) <???>
...
@property (strong) EOPSessionsViewController *sessionsVC;
```

then:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.sessionsVC.blurEffectView removeFromSuperview];
}
```